# How to remove color from print to make it suitable for piping

Tags: bash, awk, find, colors

I'm piping some Unix commands with my own scripts. The problem is that in my scripts, I'm using colors. Like for example:

```
yellow=`tput setaf 3`
reset=`tput sgr0`

function Warning()
{
    echo "${yellow}$*${reset}"
}
```

I have a command that prints the path of some directories, using `Warning "Compress $directory"`.

I want to pipe it into the find command.

I'm using:

```
./compress.sh | grep Push | awk '{print $2}' | while read directory; do find $directory | wc -l; done;
```

However, I get this error:

> find: ‘/some_directory\033(B\033[m’: No such file or directory
> 0

It seems that either `awk` puts some invisible characters to the end of its print, or the color messes up with piping.

Why do I get this error? What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Terminal colors work via escape sequences. `${yellow}` is really `\033[0;33m` (or `\e[0;33m`) and `${reset}` is `\033[0m`. You can try it out with `echo -e '\e[0;33m yellow \e[0m'` ([list of the basic color codes](https://gist.github.com/Prakasaka/219fe5695beeb4d6311583e79933a009)).

`\033` means the char with the octal number 033, that's Escape in ASCII and Unicode. `\e` is another way to mean Escape. The `[` marks the start and the `m` marks the end of the code.

Most programs can't interpret color codes, so you have to disable them if you are piping. You can [detect if your program is running in a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911213/5965450), when `[[ -t 1 ]]` is true, you are writing to a terminal, if it is false you are writing elsewhere, probably a pipe.

This will only output colors when you are printing to a terminal:

```bash
yellow=''
reset=''
if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
    yellow=`tput setaf 3`
    reset=`tput sgr0`
fi

function Warning()
{
    echo "${yellow}$*${reset}"
}
```

Comment: That is the proper approach.